# How to create a custom DB Query Builder method in Laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-query-builder

I'm searching a way to create a custom DB query method something similar to Eloquent scope.

For example

```
class User extends Eloquent 
{
    public function getActiveUsers()
    {
        //...
        //...
        $data = DB::table('myTable')
            ->where('active', 1)
            ->myFun($var1, $var2) //<-- custom method
            ->limit(10)->get();
        dd($data);
    }
}
```

And in `myFun()` I will have some thing like this

```
public function myFun()
{
    if(condition 1)
    {
        $query->where('col', 12)
    }
    if(condition 2)
    {
        $query->where($va2, 'test')
    }
}
```

And finally this where clause will be added to the main query.

I found [this solution](https://laravel.io/index.php/forum/03-10-2015-how-to-properly-create-a-custom-query-builder-method), but it is for Laravel 5. I'm looking for Laravel 4.2.

Please note: *The application is in production phase so I can't use Eloquent scope, so I'm looking to create some thing similar to that.*

Comment: I think you can use `DB::listen(function($sql){})` there you can get query instance in one line.

Answer (score -1):

AS per your requirement follow the below concept :

```
class User extends Eloquent 
{
    public $query = null;
    public function getActiveUsers()
    {
        //...
        //...
        $this->query  = DB::table('myTable');
        $this->myFun($var1, $var2) //<-- custom method
        $data = $this->query->limit(10)->get();
        dd($data);
    }

    public function myFun()
    {
        if(condition 1)
        {
            $this->query->where('col', 12);
        }
        if(condition 2)
        {
            $this->query->where($va2, 'test');
        }

        $this->query->where('active', 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I know this way, but I'm looking for something exactly similar to scope. i.e., I'll write `DB::table('myTable')->myFun($var1, $var2);` **NOT** `DB::table('myTable'); $this->myFun($var1, $var2);` In short in a single line like eloquent scope. I don't know is it possible or not.